# Mysql2 segmentation fault ubuntu22.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mariadb, mysql2, ubuntu-22.04

I've been struggling on mysql2's the segmentation fault issue since last 2days. I've tried multiple solution but those are not resolved the issue. Ubuntu version is 22.04, [Mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#linux-and-other-unixes) version is 0.5.3, ruby version is 2.7.4. I installed mysql-server & it is also running fine in my local. The solution is tried from this link - [mysql2 Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611763/mysql2-segmentation-fault-at-0x0000000000000000) but the library - **libmariadbclient-dev** is not available so I've replaced to **libmariadb-dev-compat** and **libmariadb-dev**. Even though the issue is not resolved yet.

```
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0053 p:---- s:0284 e:000283 CFUNC  :connect
c:0052 p:0565 s:0272 e:000271 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90 [FINISH]
c:0051 p:---- s:0258 e:000257 CFUNC  :new
c:0050 p:0017 s:0253 e:000252 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/m
c:0049 p:0118 s:0247 e:000245 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/m [FINISH]
c:0048 p:---- s:0241 e:000240 CFUNC  :public_send
c:0047 p:0021 s:0235 e:000234 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0046 p:0021 s:0231 e:000230 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0045 p:0014 s:0227 e:000226 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0044 p:0012 s:0221 e:000220 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0043 p:0011 s:0215 e:000213 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0042 p:0021 s:0209 e:000205 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0041 p:0299 s:0202 e:000201 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/a
c:0040 p:0014 s:0192 e:000191 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.r
c:0039 p:0003 s:0188 e:000187 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.r
c:0038 p:0027 s:0184 e:000183 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_
c:0037 p:0010 s:0176 e:000175 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_
c:0036 p:0018 s:0172 e:000171 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.
c:0035 p:0006 s:0164 e:000163 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.
c:0034 p:0024 s:0160 e:000159 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks. [FINISH]
c:0033 p:---- s:0156 e:000155 CFUNC  :each
c:0032 p:0023 s:0152 e:000151 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks. [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0148 e:000147 CFUNC  :each
c:0030 p:0063 s:0144 e:000143 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.
c:0029 p:0016 s:0137 e:000136 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.
c:0028 p:0020 s:0131 e:000130 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.ra
c:0027 p:0008 s:0128 e:000127 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281 [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0124 e:000123 CFUNC  :each
c:0025 p:0146 s:0120 e:000119 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281
c:0024 p:0009 s:0114 e:000113 METHOD /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/airbrake-11.0.3/lib/airbrake/rake.rb:17
c:0023 p:0141 s:0108 E:0009d8 BLOCK  /home/karthick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@sdf_crawlboardv3_20210825/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0104 e:000103 CFUNC  :synchronize
```

Comment: Hi Karthick, Did you solve this error? If yes then post the result.I am also facing this issue now. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Manivannan Jeganathan. Did you solve this error? Even I got the same issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-mysql-config=$(brew --prefix mysql@5.7)/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

This solved my problem on MacOS. It seems mysql2 has some requirements for OpenSSL that must be included when we install it as a gem.

Comment: Anyone faced same issue for ubuntu 22.04 version, please update answer if any