# BUG Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000 in mysql2 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2, ruby-2.5

I am using

ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x86_64-linux] )

Rails 5.0.7.2

while execute the rails c command it throws below error -

```
`
`home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0044 p:---- s:0331 e:000330 CFUNC  :connect
c:0043 p:0614 s:0319 e:000318 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90 [FINISH]
c:0042 p:---- s:0305 e:000304 CFUNC  :new
c:0041 p:0142 s:0300 e:000299 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:25
c:0040 p:0024 s:0293 e:000292 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729
c:0039 p:0021 s:0289 e:000288 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773
c:0038 p:0016 s:0285 e:000284 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752
c:0037 p:0014 s:0279 e:000278 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:713
c:0036 p:0012 s:0273 e:000271 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490
c:0035 p:0031 s:0267 e:000263 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364
c:0034 p:0046 s:0260 e:000259 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883
c:0033 p:0011 s:0253 e:000252 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128
c:0032 p:0004 s:0249 e:000248 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91
c:0031 p:0012 s:0245 e:000244 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559`


`[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted (core dumped)
`
```

can you give any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: These might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611763/mysql2-segmentation-fault-at-0x0000000000000000 https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby/issues/150