# Mysql2 Segmentation fault in ruby with ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, segmentation-fault, mysql2, ubuntu-22.04, ruby-2.5

I am trying to run query in rails console, but it gives Segmentation fault error, Ubuntu 22.04, MySql version 8.0,36, ruby 2.5.3, rails, 5.1.4
Here is my error output when I run any query in console,

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:97: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0052 p:---- s:0319 e:000318 CFUNC  :connect
c:0051 p:0672 s:0307 e:000306 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/lib/mysql2/client.rb:97 [FINISH]
c:0050 p:---- s:0292 e:000291 CFUNC  :new
c:0049 p:0104 s:0287 e:000286 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:21
c:0048 p:0024 s:0280 e:000279 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0047 p:0021 s:0276 e:000275 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0046 p:0015 s:0272 e:000271 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0045 p:0014 s:0266 e:000265 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0044 p:0012 s:0260 e:000258 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0043 p:0038 s:0254 e:000250 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0042 p:0046 s:0247 e:000246 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
c:0041 p:0011 s:0240 e:000239 METHOD /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-
```

I tried these steps to resolve the issue,

1. Reinstalled mysql latest version 8.0.36.
2. Also tried executing these steps: [mysql2 Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611763/mysql2-segmentation-fault-at-0x0000000000000000)

   ```bash
   sudo apt remove libmariadbd-dev
   sudo apt install libmariadbd-dev
   gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.6'
   ```

But nothing works, still same issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Old, long out of support version of Ruby on a fairly new Ubuntu version. Likely something to do with ssl and also possible that you are stuck.

Comment: @dbugger. Thanks for your reply, I already updated ssl pkg while installing ruby 2.5.3 . `OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014`
 This is the ssl version I'm using here, Will it be the issue then, shall I downgrade this then? Can you suggest which to use?

Comment: Can't you at least upgrade Ruby to 2.5.9 and Rails to 5.1.7 which are the latest of those major versions?

Comment: @ 
Ben Trewern As it is a production server, if I update ruby I need to test whole application workings, which will be more complex in current case. Could you please suggest any other solution for this ?

Comment: @dbugger, Thank you for pointing out the openssl checks, really that was the issue, I tried reinstalling ruby with ssl and thus it worked... Great thanks.. If any one stuck here they can refer this doc for updating ssl https://deanpcmad.com/2022/installing-older-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 0):

Try these below steps:

1. Install openssl from this doc https://deanpcmad.com/2022/installing-older-ruby-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04/

2. If you are using rvm you can execute the below command to install Ruby for this ssl version support after openssl-1.1.1g installation from above doc

   ```
   rvm install "ruby-2.5.3" --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.openssl/openssl-1.1.1g
   ```